# Splitting PyTorch Geometric custom data to train and test

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

Working with Data (torch_geometric.data import Data) I want to split it to train and test for an edge classification task (labels provided as a pandas column) based on pandas column values (Month in my code example). I am having errors derived from wrong edge indexes:

IndexError: Encountered an index error. Please ensure that all indices in 'edge_index' point to valid indices in the interval [0, 1] (got interval [0, 2])

Here is a code example:

```
def create_graph_data(df):
  node_labels = df['Source'].append(df['Target']).unique()
  node_indices = {label: index for index, label in enumerate(node_labels)}
  x = torch.tensor(df[['NodeFeature1', 'NodeFeature2']].values, dtype=torch.float)
  y = torch.tensor(pd.DataFrame([df['Label_1'].values, df['Label_2'].values]).T.values, dtype=torch.float)

  edge_index = []
  for source, target in zip(df['Source'], df['Target']):
      source_idx = node_indices[source]
      target_idx = node_indices[target]
      edge_index.append([source_idx, target_idx])
  edge_index = torch.tensor(edge_index, dtype=torch.long).t().contiguous()

  edge_attr = torch.tensor(df[['EdgeFeature1', 'EdgeFeature2']].values, dtype=torch.float)
  data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index, edge_attr=edge_attr, y=y)
  return data
```

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from torch_geometric.data import Data
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv, GATConv

df = pd.DataFrame({'Source': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D'],
                   'Target': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
                   'EdgeFeature1': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6],
                   'EdgeFeature2': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.4],
                   'NodeFeature1': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2],
                   'NodeFeature2': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3],
                   'Month':[4,4,4,5,5],
                   'Label_1': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   'Label_2': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]})

df_train = df[df['Month']<5]
df_test = df[df['Month']==5]

data_train = create_graph_data(df_train)
data_test = create_graph_data(df_test)

class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, edge_attr_dim, hidden_channels):
        super(GCN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GATConv(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = GATConv(in_channels=hidden_channels, out_channels=2)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index, edge_attr = data.x, data.edge_index, data.edge_attr
        # x = torch.cat([x, edge_attr], dim=1)
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x

model = GCN(in_channels=2, edge_attr_dim=2, hidden_channels=16)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

for epoch in range(100):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(data_train)
    loss = criterion(out.squeeze(), data_train.y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    pred = model(data_test).squeeze()

print(pred)
```